# Zend :: Changing get parameters from controller/action?param=value to controller/action/param/value

Tags: forms, zend-framework, url, redirect, get

i have a form with get method. on submit the query string appears in the url after ? mark. but i want it to be zend like url

From  : 
controller/action?param=value
to:
controller/action/param/value

Should i use javascript to redirect ?
Or create a helper function zend that do the job ?
Is there a better solution for that ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your action.
Suppose your form action is like `'somecontroller/test'`

```
Public function testAction(){
//codes

//You must be redirecting like this
$this->_redirect('/anothercontroller/fooaction?param=value');

//You can change that to
$this->_redirect('/anothercontroller/fooaction/param/value');

}
```

So that you can get that value in that fooaction

```
 $this->_request->getParam('param');
```

Comment: thank you for your your answer but its not what i need. On submit form  i get in the url the params with ? mark. what i want is zend like url : controller/action/param/value not controller/action?param=value